# node.js on windows : Is it possible to get the absolute path of process from its pid?

Tags: node.js, windows

I would like to get the path of a running process on Windows os
[image]

[image]

I can find his pid in node.js

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('tasklist', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            var lines = stdout.toString().split('\n');
            var results = new Array();
            lines.forEach(function (line) {
                if (line.indexOf('GestionDocument') > -1) {
                    console.log(line);
                    var parts = line.split(/[\s,]+/);
                    console.log(parts[1]);
                }
});
```

that displays me

> 16248

Do you know how to get path folder of a process from his pid?